# How to use getall with orderby in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

i want to list records where id=1 between two timestamps and finally order them according to timestamp.

Mysql query something:

```
Select * from test 
where (timestamp between 100099323 AND 1423699323) AND id=1 
order by timestamp
```

there are more than 5 million documents in rethink database.

I tried using index for the simple mysql query:

```
Select * from test where id=1 order by timestamp
```

and Rethinkdb query is:

```
r.table('test').getAll(1, {index: 'id'}).orderBy({index: 'timestamp'})
```

but i am getting error:

```
RqlRuntimeError: Indexed order_by can only be performed on a TABLE or 
TABLE_SLICE in:
r.table("test").getAll(1, {index: "id"}).orderBy({index: "timestamp"})
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

RethinkDB doesn't support efficient index intersection (the Github issue to add this is [#809](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/809)), but you could implement this query efficiently by adding a compound index for the 'id' and 'timestamp' indexes.

If your result set is small enough, though, the `orderBy` could just be done completely in-memory by dropping the 'index' optarg:

```
r.table("test").getAll(1, {index: "id"}).orderBy("timestamp")
```

To do this efficiently for large result sets, you would need an index.  Assuming your 'id' and 'timestamp' indexes correspond directly to fields in your rows, adding the index would look like:

```
r.table("test").indexCreate("id_time",
                            function(row) {
                                return [row("id"), row("timestamp")];
                            })
```

To get all the rows with `id=1` and sort by the timestamp, you would then run:

```
r.table("test").between([1], [2], {"index": "id_time"})
               .orderBy({"index": "id_time"})
```

In addition, going back to the original query you posted, you could query between two timestamps for `id=1` by running:

```
r.table("test").between([1, <time 1>], [1, <time 2>], {"index": "id_time"})
               .orderBy({"index": "id_time"})
```