# RethinkDB getAll ordered by date with index

Tags: python, python-2.7, rethinkdb

*I've seen questions very similar to this, but none of the answers are ideal because they're either inefficient or don't work.*

I have a database table which has the following rows:

`id  feed  datetime  content`

I need to iterate over every item in the table where `feed` is `example` (or any other value; always a string) but the iteration needs to be ordered by `datetime`.

Unfortunately I can't do it in memory because there could be hundreds of thousands of entries for a single user.

I've tried modifying code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583653/how-to-use-getall-with-orderby-in-rethinkdb) and didn't make any progress. I've also adapted the best answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747207/rethinkdb-index-for-filter-orderby) and get an error when I run this;

`print r.db('main').table('data').between([feedid, r.minval], [feedid, r.maxval], index="feedByTime").order_by(index="feedByTime").run(conn)`

Which throws this error;

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 196, in __str__
    val_str = ', '.join(map(repr, self.items[:10]))
TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'`

If I remove `index="feedByTime"` from `between`, I get this error instead;

`rethinkdb.errors.ReqlQueryLogicError: Cannot order by index 'feedByTime' after calling BETWEEN on index 'id'`

The index (`feedByTime`) was made like so;

`r.db('main').table('data').index_create("feedByTime", lambda x: [x["feed"], x["datetime"]]).run(conn)`

Any suggestions would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: That code looks correct to me.  Are you running the latest version of the Python driver?

Comment: @mlucy Yeah, everything is on the latest version. Nothing I've tried is working, I must be missing something.

Comment: That error looks like it might be a bug in the Python driver.  I would open a bug on the GitHub issue tracker: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues

Comment: Yes, I believe that might be the case. I edited the Python Driver to add an exception which 'fixed' it. I'll open a bug report. Seems like it just needs to handle that exception in a more friendly way rather than halting the whole query from being run. I hadn't actually considered a Driver bug before your comment, so thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query has an issue:

Instead of

```
query = (
    r.db('main').table('data')
     .between(
         [feedid, r.minval],
         [feedid, r.maxval],
         index="feedByTime"
     )
     .order_by(index="feedByTime")
     .run(conn)
)
```

Try

```
query = (
    r.db('main').table('data')
     .between(
         [feedid, r.minval],
         [feedid, r.maxval],
         index="feedByTime"
     )
     .order('datetime')
     .run(conn)
)
```